# How to xml to xml parse

Tags: xml, rss, google-spreadsheets, parsing

I am trying to automate this process.

I have link to this xml file. it has many parameters, but I am only interested in 3 of it's parameters. I want to use those 3 parameter and create new xml file automactially with different tag names.

see screenshot.

Original XML file.[XML File](http://www.in.com/getvideoxml-100415387-n.xml)

I am only interested in all the `//item/image"`,`//item/source/file_details/file`, and `//item/title`.

How can I automatically create another XML file and get all these parameters there with different meta names?

I have tried importing `importxml` in Google spreadsheet but don't know how to create XML from it.

final result should be like this.
`http://blog.defaultroute.com/2011/01/04/building-a-roku-channel-part-2/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a Java Application to do the trick.

E.g. to read the data you need:

```
File fXmlFile = new File(fileName);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();


        NodeList playlists = doc.getElementsByTagName("playlist");      // Get all Nodes named 'playlist'
        if(playlists != null && playlists.getLength() > 0){
            for (int temp = 0; temp < playlists.getLength(); temp++) {     // Iterate through all 'playlists'
                if(playlists.item(temp).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){     //Check if they are Elements (just to be sure)
                    Element playlist = (Element) playlists.item(temp);       // Cast to Element

                    NodeList items = playlist.getElementsByTagName("item");     // Get Nodes named 'item' in 'playlist'

                    for (int temp1 = 0; temp1 < items.getLength(); temp1++) {       // Iterate through all items
                        if(items.item(temp1).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                            Element item = (Element) items.item(temp1);

                            NodeList imgs = item.getElementsByTagName("image");
                            Node img = imgs.item(0);              // We suppose there is only one image-node in the item-node
                            if(img.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                                Element image = (Element) img;
                                String imgUrl = image.getTextContent();      // Get the textContent of image --> Store it in an Array(List) etc...                                      
                            }               
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Of course you got to do the same for the other Nodes too.

And write it back in an XML File using the DocumentBuilder.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();


Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("playlist");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);

Element item = doc.createElement("item");
rootElement.appendChild(item);

Element image = doc.createElement("image");
item.appendChild(image);
image.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("HERE YOUR ImgURL "));

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(fileName)); 
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you so much..I haven't started working on it, but I am sure this is the way to approach.